# Drupal Views Argument from URL

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have 2 views inside of drupal:

View #1) lists of terms(field of a content type) linked to view #2(passing an argument to select the term in the drop-down)
View #2) drop-down of the terms from view #1, content filtered based on term selected in drop-down.

I'd like to pass an argument from the links on view #1 to change the drop-down on view#2

Can this be done with an argument, or do I need to figure out some PHP to handle this..Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it on views, but to prepopulate node add/edit forms from URL arguments the prepopulate module works quite well, so maybe it's worth a try:
http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate